# SML List [1, 2, 3,...n]

Tags: sml, smlnj

I need to create a list [1,2,3...n] without using pre implemented List fuctions. I can make the list backwards by writing :

```
fun makeList(x : int) = 
if x = 0
then []
else x :: makeList(x-1)
```

Then I could reverse it and get [1,2,3,4] if inputting 4. How would I do this in only one function?

Comment: Re: "How would I do this in only one function?": Can you elaborate on this requirement? Maybe I'm just not imaginative enough, but I can't see how you'd do this without any helper functions at all. Are you not even allowed to define a helper function in a `let`-expression?

Comment: Please post the exact requirements. You can write one function that has an arbitrary number of local function definitions, but it's not clear whether that counts as "one" function. (If you're not allowed local definitions, this is impossible, so an educated guess is that you're interpreting "one" too strictly.)

Answer (score 2):

You've made the reverse list in one function and without using the List library.

To make it in the right order, you can use an accumulating argument:

```
fun makeList 0 result = result
  | makeList n result = makeList (n-1) (n :: result)
```

Testing this:

```
- makeList 10 [];
> val it = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] : int list
```

This function takes an extra argument in which it accumulates the result in the right order.

This is what trips up other correspondents in this Q&A and what has made previous answerers delete their responses: Either you accept that this `makeList` takes an extra empty list as initial argument, which is kind of messy, or you nest this function inside another function that hides this mechanism:

```
fun makeList n =
  let fun go 0 result = result
        | go i result = go (i-1) (i :: result)
  in go n [] end
```

But then you would not have used *one* function. Unless you mean one *exposed* function, since the inner function is only available in the context of the definition of `makeList`. As the problem statement is unclear about this, answering can be unsatisfactory.

Either you make *one* function, and allow for its type signature to be different (taking an extra argument), or you make one *exposed* function and allow for it to have an inner function that accumulates the result in reverse.